# ListView adapter switches seekbars position while scrolling

Tags: java, android

I am developing chat app with three different chat messages text ,photo and audio messages my problem now with audio message which consists of button , *textview* and seekbar so when button clicked seekbar and textview get updated.

```
  //global variables
    Context context;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private List<RowItem> items = null;
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    String audioFileURL;
    ViewHolder clicked_holder = null;
    private SeekBarUpdater seekBarUpdater;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

  public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
                             List<RowItem> items) {
    super(context, resourceId, items);
    this.context = context;
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
    this.items = items;
    seekBarUpdater = new SeekBarUpdater();
}


 private static class ViewHolder {
    public com.example.truth.lang.messanger.RoundedImageView imageView;
    public TextView msgText;
    public TextView msgDate;
    public  SeekBar seekBar_message;
    public ImageView play_audio;
    public LinearLayout.LayoutParams params;
    public LinearLayout.LayoutParams audioparams;
    public LinearLayout linearLayout;
    public LinearLayout audio_layout;
    public RelativeLayout intermediate_bar;
    public TextView audio_duration;
    public TextView audio_date;
    int pos;


}



   //this is getView();
if (convertView == null) {
..... convertView.setTag(holder);


    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    holder.play_audio.setTag(holder);
                holder.play_audio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        if (items.get(position).getAudio_url() != null) {
                             try {
                                if (mediaPlayer != null&&clicked_holder!=null) {
                                  //check if there any media playing 
                                    if(position!=clicked_holder.pos){
                                        clicked_holder.seekBar_message.setProgress(0);
                                        clicked_holder.play_audio.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_audio_icon_1);
                                        clicked_holder.intermediate_bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        clicked_holder.play_audio.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        clicked_holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
                                        clicked_holder.pos=position;

                                        if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                                            mediaPlayer.stop();
                                            mediaPlayer.reset();
                                            mediaPlayer=(null);
                                        }
                                       clicked_holder.intermediate_bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        clicked_holder.play_audio.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                         mediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();

                                        audioFileURL = items.get(position).getAudio_url();
                                        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                                        try {
                                            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(audioFileURL);
                                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }

                                        }
                                        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                                        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                                clicked_holder.play_audio.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause_audio_icon);
                                                mp.start();

                                                if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                                                    clicked_holder.intermediate_bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                    clicked_holder.play_audio.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                    updatePlayingView();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });


                                    }else{
                                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                                    clicked_holder.intermediate_bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    clicked_holder.play_audio.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    clicked_holder.play_audio.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_audio_icon_1);
                                    clicked_holder.seekBar_message.setProgress(0);
                                    mediaPlayer=null;
                                    clicked_holder=null;
                                }
                                } else  {

                                    clicked_holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
                                    clicked_holder.pos=position;
                                    holder.seekBar_message.setTag(position);
                                    clicked_holder.intermediate_bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    clicked_holder.play_audio.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                    mediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();

                                    audioFileURL = items.get(position).getAudio_url();
                                    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                                    try {
                                        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(audioFileURL);
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                                    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                            clicked_holder.play_audio.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause_audio_icon);
                                            mp.start();

                                            if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                                                clicked_holder.intermediate_bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                clicked_holder.play_audio.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                updatePlayingView();


                                            }
                                        }
                                    });

      mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

                                            @Override
                                            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                                clicked_holder.play_audio.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_audio_icon_1);


                                                mediaPlayer=null;
                                                clicked_holder.seekBar_message.setProgress(0);
                                                clicked_holder.play_audio.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_audio_icon_1);
                                                Log.i("holderpositionupdate1", "media player");
                                                updateNonPlayingView(clicked_holder);
                                                clicked_holder=null;

                                            }
                                        });
                                    mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                                            Log.i("setOnErrorListener",""+what+" "+ extra);

                                            return true;
                                        }
                                    });
                                }


                            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
                                e1.printStackTrace();

                            } catch (SecurityException e1) {
                                e1.printStackTrace();

                            }
                        }else {
                            clicked_holder.intermediate_bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            clicked_holder.play_audio.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

**strong text**

and i am updating my seekbar like this ...

```
private void updateNonPlayingView(ViewHolder clicked_holder) {
        clicked_holder.seekBar_message.removeCallbacks(seekBarUpdater);
        clicked_holder.seekBar_message.setEnabled(true);
        clicked_holder.seekBar_message.setProgress(0);
    }


 private void updatePlayingView() {

  if(mediaPlayer!=null){

    clicked_holder.seekBar_message.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration()); 

    clicked_holder.seekBar_message.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());             

        clicked_holder.seekBar_message.setEnabled(true);

        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            clicked_holder.seekBar_message.postDelayed(seekBarUpdater, 100); 
        }

    }else {
            clicked_holder.seekBar_message.removeCallbacks(seekBarUpdater);
        }
    }
    private class SeekBarUpdater implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (clicked_holder!=null) {
                if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying() ) {        
                    clicked_holder.seekBar_message.postDelayed(this, 100);
                  //also update my textview with audio time left til finsish
                } 
            } 
        }
    }
```

**strong text**
Now my seekbar gets updated right and reset to its normal as long as no scrolling but when ever scroll the screen other seekbars gets updated randomly i think i needed to update my seekbar only when it is visible and reset all visible seekbar progress to zero but i can not achieve this i have tried a lot for 2 weeks now but with no progress any help.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are recycling view using viewholder. Your postDelayed method doesn't know that the view is now recycled and used for creating a new raw in the listView.

One possible solution is to not recycle your views, which however may not be efficient in case your list is large enough.

Comment: igave this a thought but i this will affect user experience badly

Comment: If the list is not very large it won't affect much.

Comment: thanks for your help but i could not make it work yet

Comment: i have defined global variable to hold clicked posistion >>int clicked_row; and in holder class defined >> int pos;  then whenever seekbar view gets clicked i am updating pos variable>> clicked_holder.pos=position; and  clicked_row=position then in my runnable i checked if(clicked_holder.pos== clicked_row) then postdelay

Comment: what i have noticed my clicked_holder gets recycled again with same position value so it keeps updating random views when scroll...if you could explain your answer with some code i will be so happy because this consumed a lot of time now thanks for your concern